# What is known for $f(3(z+1))$ if $f(z+1)=cf(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If I know $f(z+1)=cf(z)$ for a constant $c$ and a complex function $f$, can I say something about $f(3(z+1))$?

$f(3z+3)=cf(3z+2)=c^2 f(3z+1)=c^3f(3z)$.

Is this right?

Comment: It should be $c^3f(3z)$ at the end.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $c=e^a$ (assuming $\neq 0$) and note that 
$$ g(z)=e^{-az}f(z) = e^{-a(z+1)} cf(z) = e^{-a(z+1)} f(z+1)=g(z+1)$$
Thus $f(z)$ can be written as $f(z)=e^{az}g(z)$ where $g$ is any 1-periodic function. Your stated identity is correct. To say more you need to know the domain of $f$ (integers, real, complex).